# NodeJS/MySQL: Use Results of Previous SELECT Query?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, backend

Building a simple ToDo app in React/NodeJS/Express with MySQL. Users join a group ("family" in the code), then tasks are viewable filtered by familyId. To create a task, I first have a query that finds the user's familyId from the Users table, then I want to include that familyId value in the subsequent INSERT query for creating the task row in the Tasks table. My task.model.js is below:

```
const sql = require("./db.js");

// constructor
const Task = function(task) {
    this.title = task.title;
    this.familyId = task.familyId;
    this.description = task.description;
    this.completed = task.completed;
    this.startDate = task.startDate;
    this.userId = task.userId;
};

Task.create = (task, result) => {
    sql.query("SELECT familyId FROM users WHERE userId = ?", task.userId, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error selecting from USERS: ", err);
            return result(err, null);
        }
        sql.query("INSERT INTO tasks (familyId, title, description, completed, startDate) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", [result, task.title, task.description, task.completed, task.startDate], (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error inserting in TASKS: ", err);
                return result(err, null);
            }
        })
        console.log("created task: ", { id: res.insertId, ...task });
        return result(null, { id: res.insertId, ...task });
    });
};
```

However, I cannot figure out how to properly use the familyId result of the SELECT query as a parameter in the suqsequent INSERT query. I know the overall syntax works because I can manually plug in an ID value as a parameter and the entire operation completes successfully - I just need to know how to use the resule of the first query in the next.

Comment: what error are you getting

Comment: I get different errors depending on what I try to do for result. This one is common: "val.slice is not a function", or also "[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are using it should work but the problem is you have defined the callback as res but are passing result in the 2nd sql query

```
sql.query("SELECT familyId FROM users WHERE userId = ?", task.userId, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error selecting from USERS: ", err);
        return result(err, null);
    }
    //res should have the value for the familyId of the given user so in next line pass res not result
    sql.query("INSERT INTO tasks (familyId, title, description, completed, startDate) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", [res[0].familyId, task.title, task.description, task.completed, task.startDate], (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error inserting in TASKS: ", err);
            return result(err, null);
        }
    })
    console.log("created task: ", { id: res.insertId, ...task });
    return result(null, { id: res.insertId, ...task });
});
```

Comment: Excellent, that worked. Thanks for the explanation, will read up on this more and get educated.

Comment: i had edited the answer assuming the result is actually an array of json you can check the same , if its an array of json with all columns you need to use something like res[0].familyId otherwise if it gives only the familyId use res, depends on how res is returned adding a simple console.log(res) before the 2nd query can help you find that

Answer (score 1):

> SQL returns array in result , so use result[0] to get first Object ,
> and then access the object key by result[0].keyName

```
Task.create = (task, result) => {
        sql.query("SELECT familyId FROM users WHERE userId = ?", task.userId, (err, users) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error selecting from USERS: ", err);
                return result(err, null);
            }

            let familyId = users && users[0] ? users[0].familyId : null;

            sql.query("INSERT INTO tasks (familyId, title, description, completed, startDate) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", [familyId, task.title, task.description, task.completed, task.startDate], (err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error inserting in TASKS: ", err);
                    return result(err, null);
                }
            })
            console.log("created task: ", { id: res.insertId, ...task });
            return result(null, { id: res.insertId, ...task });
        });
    };
```

Comment: is the return value array of sql rows i am not sure about depends on the sql layer he uses that but the actual error seems like that he was using the wrong variable